# Como puedo poner mi formControl como invalid, para que este deshabilitado mi boton

Tags: angular, formularios

Estoy intentando que mi boton quede deshabilitado a menos que la confirmacion de la contraseña coincida con la contraseña

```
constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){ }

resetPasswordForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    securityQuestion: ['', Validators.required],
    answerQuestion: ['', Validators.required],
    newPassword : ['', Validators.required],
    confirmPassword : ['', Validators.required];
});
```

Este es mi `form builder` y esto son mis `getters` y mi `funcion`

```
get email(){
    return this.resetPasswordForm.get('email');
}
get securityQuestion(){
    return this.resetPasswordForm.get('securityQuestion');
}
get answerQuestion(){
    return this.resetPasswordForm.get('answerQuestion');
}
get newPassword(){
    return this.resetPasswordForm.get('newPassword');
}
get confirmPassword(){
    return this.resetPasswordForm.get('confirmPassword');
}

verifyPassword(){
    console.log(this.resetPasswordForm.get('confirmPassword'));

    if(this.resetPasswordForm.get("newPassword").value === this.resetPasswordForm.get('confirmPassword').value)
    {
        return this.resetPasswordForm.get('confirmPassword');
    }else{
        return this.resetPasswordForm.get('confirmPassword');   
    }
    console.log(this.resetPasswordForm.get('confirmPassword'));
}
```

---

Estos son los `formControls` que quiero poner como `invalid` o `valid` y estan dentro del `[formGroup]="resetPasswordForm"`

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="email.valid && securityQuestion.valid &&answerQuestion.valid">
<label for="newPassword">New password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="newPassword" placeholder="Write a new password"
pattern="^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{8,16}$" 
formControlName="newPassword" 
[class.is-invalid]="newPassword.touched && newPassword.invalid">
```

---

yyyy

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="email.valid && securityQuestion.valid &&answerQuestion.valid">
<label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm your password"
formControlName="confirmPassword"
[class.is-invalid]="confirmPassword.touched && confirmPassword.invalid"
(keyup)="verifyPassword()">
<small *ngIf="confirmPassword.touched && !(confirmPassword.value === newPassword.value)" class="text-danger">This password is not equal.</small>
```

---

Este es el boton final:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!resetPasswordForm.valid">Reset password</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadir un validador "global", que tenga acceso a varios elementos (FormControl) del formulario. Lo has de declarar aparte, añadiéndolo al FormGroup, no a un FormControl en particular.

Te pongo un ejemplo sencillo, usando un formulario con sólo dos campos (los de contraseña y confirmación) para evitar meter *ruido* y veas que es realmente sencillo una vez sabes cómo hacerlo:

El código del componente sería así:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dataForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
      password1: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      password2: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
    },
    //validador para todo el formulario
    {validator: this.checkPasswords });

  }

  getErrorMsg():string {
    if (this.dataForm.valid) {
      return '';
    }
    let err = this.dataForm.errors;
    if (err && err.notSame) { //aquí sólo aparecen los errores globales!
      return 'Las contraseñas no son iguales'
    }
    return 'Las contraseñas tienen menos de 3 caracteres';
  }

  checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
    let pass = group.get("password1").value;
    let confirmPass = group.get("password2").value;

    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true };
  }
}
```

y la plantilla HTML podría ser algo como:

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
    <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password1">
 <input placeholder="Confirm Password" formControlName="password2">

</form>
<div *ngIf="!dataForm.valid">{{getErrorMsg()}}</div>
```

Puedes verlo en ejecución [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-validation-p13)